# How do I enter the sewer pipe under The Oasis?

Tags: steamworld-dig-2

Underneath The Oasis, there is a sewer pipe marked as a cavern entrance on the mini-map. I can reach the pipe by swimming through the radioactive "moon juice" under the town, but there are iron bars blocking the entrance.

I tried to use my pick-axe and grenade launcher to break the bars, but I don't have enough range from the small patch of land nearby.

**How do I enter the sewer pipe underneath The Oasis?**

[image: Sewer pipe under The Oasis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep going through the game, you will not be able to go through there til the end.

> Toward the end of the game, you have to return to the Oasis but the entrance gets blocked due to some events. You'll have to find another way in and that pipe is the exit for the alternate entrance.

Comment: Having played a bit further, you can unlock the sewer early once you find the “Ramjet Vigor” upgrade for the jetpack.